# Lagrange multiplier and minimum variance

Tags: stochastic-processes, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, monte-carlo

Looking into a control variate technique of Monte Carlo simulation I have run into a cost-optimization problem that I'm not quite sure I understand. It seems it has to do with Lagrangian multipliers, but I am not positive about this so if someone can give a hint about the following problem I'll be very glad to hear his/her take on this.

Let's say we want to estimate $\mathbb E[f_1]$, defined as
$$
\mathbb E[f_1] = \mathbb E[f_0] + \mathbb E[f_1 - f_0]
$$
for which we can use the classical Monte Carlo estimator (I'm not writing it down since it is not crucial to the problem at hand).

If we define $C_0$ and $C_1$ to be the cost of $f_0$ and $(f_1-f_0)$ respectively, and $V_0$ and $V_1$ to be the variance of $f_0$ and $(f_1-f_0)$ respectively, then we can express the cost function as 
$$
N_0C_0 + N_1C_1
$$
and the variance as 
$$
N_0^{-1}V_0 + N_1^{-1}V_1 
$$

Now the question is, how can we conclude from these two equations that for a fixed cost the variance is minimized by the expression below?
$$
\frac{N_1}{N_0} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{V_1}{C_1}}}{\sqrt{\frac{V_0}{C_0}}}
$$

From some sources it seems like I need to use the Lagrangian multiplier and that this is just a simple cost minimization problem, but I'm not sure how to get to this result.

Comment: You wish to choose $N_0,N_1$ to minimize $\frac{V_0}{N_0}+\frac{V_1}{N_1}$ given that $V_0,V_1,N_0C_0+N_1C_1$ are all held fixed? If so, then yes, that is a Lagrange multiplier problem. The gradient of $\frac{V_0}{N_0}+\frac{V_1}{N_1}$ is $\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{V_0}{N_0^2} \\ -\frac{V_1}{N_1^2} \end{bmatrix}$ while the gradient of $C_0N_0+C_1N_1$ is $\begin{bmatrix} C_0 \\ C_1 \end{bmatrix}$. Set these proportional to one another with an unknown proportionality constant $\lambda$ and solve for $N_0,N_1$ (possibly in terms of $\lambda$).

Comment: If the answer is in terms of $\lambda$, then use the cost constraint to solve for $N_0,N_1$ with no $\lambda$ involved. (It looks like there is no explicit dependence on $\lambda$ in this problem, however.)

Comment: Alternately, in this particular case you can solve for $N_1$ in terms of $N_0$ and the total cost $C$: $N_1=\frac{C-C_0N_0}{C_1}$. Substituting you now want to minimize $\frac{V_0}{N_0}+\frac{C_1 V_1}{C-C_0N_0}$, which is a one variable minimization problem. I'll post these three comments as an answer provided you confirm that I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Ian well thanks very much for your comments. I suppose I am looking for answer number 1, but I am still a bit confused. I will refer you to slides 4 and 5 of this document (https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/gilesm/talks/mcqmc12_giles.pdf) which contains the original problem, maybe that helps clearing all up.

Comment: I wrote a more detailed answer of the approach I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of the question is that you want to minimize $\frac{V_0}{N_0} + \frac{V_1}{N_1}$ given that $V_0,V_1,C_0V_0+C_1V_1$ are all held fixed. In this situation we can treat $V_0,V_1$ as parameters and solve the constrained minimization problem with the objective function $f(N_0,N_1)=\frac{V_0}{N_0}+\frac{V_1}{N_1}$ and the constraint $g(N_0,N_1)=C_0N_0+C_1N_1=C$ for some fixed $C$. To do this we introduce an additional variable $\lambda$, the Lagrange multiplier, and we solve the system of three equations:

$$\nabla f(N_0,N_1)=\lambda \nabla g(N_0,N_1) \\
g(N_0,N_1)=C.$$

The first two equations read:

$$-\frac{V_0}{N_0^2}=\lambda C_0 \\
-\frac{V_1}{N_1^2}=\lambda C_1.$$

Dividing these equations by each other we get

$$\frac{V_0 N_1^2}{V_1 N_0^2}=\frac{C_0}{C_1}.$$

Solving for $\frac{N_1}{N_0}$:

$$\frac{N_1}{N_0}=\sqrt{\frac{C_0 V_1}{C_1 V_0}}.$$

Note that this ratio can be found without knowing $C$. To actually find $N_0,N_1$ themselves, you need a specific value of $C$.

Comment: So basically what we have achieved by computing this ratio $N_1/N_0$ is obtaining expressions for both $N_0$ and $N_1$ so that, if plugged into the objective function, the variance will be the minimum possible, am I right?

Comment: @Alfie We've almost done that. If you wanted to find $N_0,N_1$ you would need to pick a $C$, substitute the ratio into the constraint, and solve the equation. Then you would have the minimum variance for that particular value of $C$. You can do this symbolically with $C$ as a parameter if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrangian is

$\mathcal L=\frac{V_0}{N_0}+\frac{V_1}{N_1}+\lambda (C-N_0\cdot C_0-N_1\cdot C_1)$

C is the cost budget or something similar. Taking the derivatives:

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial N_0 }=-\frac{V_0}{N_0 ^2}-C_0\cdot \lambda=0$

$\Rightarrow -\frac{V_0}{N_0 ^2}=C_0\cdot \lambda \quad (1)$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial N_1 }=-\frac{V_1}{N_1 ^2}-C_1\cdot \lambda=0$

$\Rightarrow -\frac{V_1}{N_1 ^2}=C_1\cdot \lambda \quad (2)$

Dividing (1) by (2):

$\frac{V_0}{V_1}\cdot \frac{N_1^2}{N_0^2}=\frac{C_0}{C_1}$

$ \frac{N_1^2}{N_0^2}=\frac{C_0}{C_1}\cdot \frac{V_1}{V_0} \quad |  \sqrt{\ \ } $

$ \frac{N_1}{N_0}=\sqrt{\frac{C_0}{C_1}\cdot \frac{V_1}{V_0} }$

This is equal to your solution.